# TitleBar Events

Tags: wpf, events, mouse, titlebar

I would like to know that, is there any way to handle Mouse events on Windows TitleBar? I want to handle some code when Mouse cursor is over Application's TitleBar.

Please give me some suggestions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In WPF the Titlebar is part of the non client area so you cannot handle events on it natively.  You might be able to do it with Win32 hooks. You can also create custom window chrome and add a custom titlebar to handle events on it yourself.

Comment: [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/131515/WPF-Custom-Chrome-Library) should help. However unless you have a very compelling reason to do it I suggest that you don't customize the titlebar. There are a lot of gotchas with doing what you want.